# Import data from .csv file to DataGrid() using Oledb Connection

Tags: vb.net, connection-string, oledbconnection, oledbcommand, oledbdataadapter

When I run this code it throws an error

> "'D:\Projects\MyTestProject\temp\2195-1480834730_Athletes.csv' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.".

I am trying to import data from a `.csv` file to a `datagrid`. FileName is `D:\Projects\MyTestProject\temp\2195-1480834730_Athletes.csv`

Thanks

```
Sub ExcelImportToGrid(ByVal filename As String, ByVal fileext As String)
        Dim strconn As String
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
        Try
            If fileext = ".xlsx" Then
                strconn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + "; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"
            ElseIf fileext = ".csv" Then
                strconn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" & filename & ";" + "Extended Properties=Text;"
            Else
                strconn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" & filename & ";" + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
            End If
            Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", strconn)
            da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Excel Data")
            da.Fill(ds)
            DataGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
            DataGrid1.DataBind()
        Catch ex As Exception
            JS_Alert(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `filename`?

Comment: D:\Projects\MyTestProject\temp\2195-1480834730_Athletes.csv

Comment: Does that file exist, in the specified path?

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with .csv/.txt files, the Connection string is supposed to have the folder path and not the exact file path.

And the Select query should have the filename and not the worksheet name

```
"Select * from [" + "Filename.csv" + "];"
```